# Replace view SQL Server with public List<> in c#.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, list

I am building a c#.net web application which draws data from a SQL Server.  I have a view in SQL Server based on a single table containing multiple records for the employees.  At most one record can be active, but it is not necessarily the one with `MAX(ID)`.  It contains the history as well as the current status of the employees.  This is some legacy I have to work with.
In order to get the correct record I group by the employee code, and total the boolean field InDienst ('currently employed'), which can be 1 at most.  Based on this selection I can go back and select the correct record applying `MAX(ID)`.

```
SELECT 
  Personeelscode_ref AS Personeelscode, 
  SUM(InDienst) AS InDienst
FROM dbo.tPersoneel
GROUP BY Personeelscode_ref
```

This works fine.
However, as I am not the only one with access to the database, I would like to move this to the c#.net controller (or a model) and apply a `List<>` statement in c# which replaces the view.  Something like this:

```
public static List<tPersoneel> listEmployeeAll = EmployeeDB.tPersoneel
            .GroupBy(x => x.Personeelscode_ref)
            .Select( new tPersoneel
            {
                Personeelscode_ref as Personeelscode,
                (InDienst).sum()
            })
            .ToList();
```

Can you show me what the correct c#.net code would be?
Thanks much in advance!

Comment: Please provide some consumable sample data. Furthermore, summing up a boolean field will not work in C#...

Comment: It comes down to grouping by a field value, and totaling a second field which is a boolean.  Is `Convert.ToInt32(InDienst)` a way to do this?  Or `Select().Distinct`?

Comment: You could perform the query via OLE command or SQL command - there you can use group by, distinct or whatever...

Comment: @Tyron78 And how do I do that? SQL command directly from c# or EF.

Comment: You can build the query directly in C#. Just google for "C# SQL OleDB" - should give quite some examples...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
List<tPersoneel> listEmployeeAll = EmployeeDB.tPersoneel.GroupBy(x => x.Personeelscode_ref)
    .Select(y => new { 
           Personeelscode = y.Key.Personeelscode_ref, 
           InDienst = y.Sum(x => x.InDienst)
    }).ToList();
```

or

```
List<tPersoneel> listEmployeeAll = (from c in EmployeeDB.tPersoneel
      group c by c.Personeelscode_ref into g
      select new
      {
         Personeelscode = y.Key.Personeelscode_ref, 
         InDienst = y.Sum(x => x.InDienst)
      }).ToList();
```